# White gap beneath footer

Tags: html, css

[On my site here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html), we're using the same CSS for different towns, but the [non populated/new towns e.g. here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/redbridge/business-directory/index.html) without content have the footer rising up and leaving a large white gap underneath.

I've tried a [sticky footer method](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) which didn't work.

Here's the footer CSS:

```
#footer-wrapper, #push {
    height: 100px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
        overflow:hidden;
}
#footer-wrapper {clear:both;width:100%;border-top:1px solid #323232;padding:20px 0 0;
background: #33383c;
background: #3F4952 url("/images/bg.jpg") repeat;
}
```

Contentwrapper:

```
#main-content {
margin: 0 5% -100px;
min-width:960px;
max-width:1137px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And I'm wondering if the right/left nav equal column CSS is affecting it e.g:

```
.right-nav {
float: right;
width: 29.4%;
border-left: 1px solid #Dddddd;
padding-top:2em;
padding-bottom:10040px;
margin-bottom:-10000px;
}
```

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page Take a look at this link. I am 100% sure this will fix it for you. Great tutorial, and it helped me a lot to on how to understand how it works!

Comment: @DiederikEEn I would not recommend using absolute positioning as it is not reliable cross-browser and cross-OS

Comment: @imulsion well aslong you are using width 100% for the footer there wont be a big problem. But I do agree with you

Comment: @DiederikEEn it should be fine in the OP's case because it is a footer div. Otherwise, it should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with `min-height:100%` on `#main-content`.

`Height:100%` cuts off the end of the page on the populated pages, whereas `min-height:100%` works on both.

Answer (score 0):

Put `min-height` on the `#main-content` div to push the footer down even if the `#main-content` div has no content.

```
#main-content {
  margin: 0 5% -100px;
  min-width:960px;
  max-width:1137px;
  min-height:600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**OR**

Add `position:absolute;` to the `#footer-wrapper` div to pull it to the bottom of the 100% height `body` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'd rather fix the root cause though and stay away from absolute positioning. Do you know what's causing it?

Comment: It is not a bug, it is just they way CSS works. Your content div is too short to push the footer down to the bottom of the window. This is the way to make the footer stick to the bottom of your page regardless of your content height.

Comment: I fixed it by adding min-height:100% to the #main-content div as per my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `height:100%;` to `#main-content`.

No idea why I didn't pick up on that before, but thanks for the replies.